# html datetime form

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I want to add a datetime input to my HTML form. Nowadays HTML5 is going to improve and only few browsers see that code `<input type="datetime">` so I don't want to use it yet).

How else can I accept a datetime input, not only with (`<input type="text">`), but also with a Javascript calendar?

Comment: Have you considered using the jQuery Datepicker?

Comment: why not, I'm using jquery also, now I'm trying to set up it and I'll hope everything will be fine :)

Comment: @AndrewOdri This seems like a question about solving a specific implementation issue, not a conceptual question like the ones Programmers would take. Programmers is also not about listing resources. I'm sorry, but your recommendation isn't a good one in this case.

Answer (score 1):

may be this is what you want http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Kishore's answer, but includes time [jQuery DateTime picker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Comment: I'd like to just add that I've had good experiences using the DateTime picker.  It comes with great built-in flexibility that extends jQuery's default DatePicker.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your profile on stackoverflow, you would see the visited link, clicking on it results the plugin you can use. This just gives you can idea as to how much customization you can do with it. If you are not using html5 `datetime`, then this is the best approach.